# Grails i18n. Query domain class and translation with one SQL select

Tags: sql, grails, internationalization, grails-orm

I'm building a Grails app that contains data that the user can enter in multiple languages. English is considered to be the default language that is shown when a translation isn't found. After a bit of browsing in this site I ended up with the following domain classes.

```
class SomeData {
    String name            // Default English name
    String description     // Default English description
    int otherData
    double moreData
    ....
    SomeDataTranslation translation
    static transients = ['translation']
    static hasMany = [translations: SomeDataTranslation]

    def getName() {
        if (translation) return translation.name
        return name
    }
}

class SomeDataTranslation {
    String languageCode
    String name            // Name in some other language
    String description     // Description in some other language
    static belongsTo = [data: SomeData]
}
```

I'm trying to set this up so that it would ideally be queried with one SQL statement. So how do I populate the transient 'translation' member variable by using GORM? The basic use case is that I need to return a list of SomeData instances as JSON and use the translated texts if they exist. So I'd like to be able to do a simple query that returns SomeData instances where the 'translation' member variable is set if a translation for the requested language exists.

I fumbled around with derived properties, but came to the conclusion that the derived property can only be derived from other properties. I wasn't able to use the language code request parameter.

**EDIT**

As per Sérgio Michels' suggestion I've been attempting to do this with HQL and I'm tantalizingly close, but still not there yet. This is what I have so far:

```
def query = 'select sd,dt from SomeData as sd, SomeDataTranslation as sdt
             where sd.name like ? and sdt.data = sd and sdt.languageCode = ?'
def queryParams =["something%", "es"]
def result = SomeData.executeQuery(query, queryParams, [readOnly: true])

def dataList = []
result.each {
    it[0].translation = it[1]
    SomeData someData = it[0]
    someData.translation = it[1]  // Fill the transient 'translation' property
    dataList << someData
}
```

The problem I have with this is that the 'where' clause filters out the SomeData instances that don't have a translation at all. I'm using the left join to ensure that the query returns all SomeData instances with the search string "something" and I want the 'translation' property to be null when no translation exists. If I remove the 'sdt.languageCode = ?' filter, I get all translations for all languages. So how do I filter the desired language while still preserving the null values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [executeQuery](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) to return both `SomeData` and `SomeDataTranslation` in one query. This will return an array to you, and then you need to assign the translation manually.

```
SomeData getSomeData() {

  def result = SomeData.executeQuery(' from SomeData sd, SomeDataTranslation sdt where sdt.data = sd', [max: 1])

  println result //[SomeData , SomeDataTranslation]

  SomeData sd = result[0]
  sd.translation = result[1]

  return sd
}
```

Worth mention that this uses [Hibernate's HQL syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) to build the query.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Unfortunately I just attempted to upgrade to grails 2.3.2 and it broke the build as usual. This seems to happen with every upgrade nowadays. I'll try reverting back to 2.3.1 in order to try this out.

Comment: I had some time to look at this now. The executeQuery() retuns a single SomeData instance, but I need to query a list of them with some criteria and I'm looking for a way to have the 'translation' property be filled on all of them.